# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined on calling WCF service on .NET 6

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, cryptography

We have an application on .NET Core 3.1 that calls a WCF service. After upgrading it to .NET 6 we are seeing the below exception during the call to the WCF service:

```
Exception: System UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
at System.Uri. CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape. UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
at System. Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at System.Xml.xmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ConvertAbsoluteUnixPathToAbsoluteUri (Strings url, xmlResolver resolver)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, XmlReaderSettings settings, Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, XmlParserContext context, Boolean closeInput) 
at System.Xml.xmlReaderSettings. CreateReader (Stream input, Uri baseUri, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Stream input, XmlReaderSettings settings, String baseUri)
at System.Security.Cryptography.xml.Utils.PreProcessStreamInput (Stream InputStream, XmlResolver xmlResolver, String baseUri)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.ExcCanonicalxml..ctor(Stream inputStream, Boolean includeComments, String inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList, XmlResolver resolver, String strBaseUri)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransform.LoadInput(Object obj)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.TransformChain. TransformToOctetStream(Object InputObject, Type inputType, XmlResolver resolver, String baseUri)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.TransformChain. TransformToOctetStream(Stream Input, XmlResolver resolver, String baseUri)
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.CalculateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
at System Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference.UpdateHashValue(XmlDocument document, CanonicalXmlNodeList refList)
at System.Security.Cryptography Xml.SignedXml.BuildDigestedReferences() 
at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.ComputeSignature()
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CompletePrimarySignatureCore (SendSecurityHeaderElement[] signatureconfirmations, SecurityToken[] signedEndorsingTokens, SecurityToken[] signedTokens, SendSecurityHeaderElement[] basicTokens, Boolean isPrimarySignature)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CreateSupportingSignature(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifier identifier)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignwithSupportingToken(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifierClause identifierClause)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignwithSupportingTokens()
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication()
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessagewriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialoffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory. TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessageAsync(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageContent.EnsureMessageEncoded()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageContent.TryComputeLength (Int64& length) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.GetComputedOrBufferLength()
at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.get_ContentLength()
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.ValidateAndNormalizeRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
....
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
at generatedProxy_1.GetCustomerInfo(CustomerInfoRequest )
at CustomerService.CustomerServiceClient.GetCustomerInfo(CustomerInfoRequest customerInfoRequest) in D:\apps\jenkins\workspace\Jenkins-build281-902370858199\src\Connected Services\CustomerService\Reference.cs:line 4442
```

This issue occurs only after upgrading to .NET 6 and only on deploying to Alpine Linux pod.

Looking at the call stack, seems like it's trying to sign the message but is failing due to a bad URI. But I am not sure which URI is causing this problem. The service URL is well formed and has a valid scheme and is resolved successfully.

Am looking for help in identifying the cause of the Invalid URI and also to learn what it is trying to sign and why?

Any help on this issue is much appreciated! Please let me know if any more information is required and I'll add. Thanks.

This is the WCF client binding:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ICustomerServiceClient, CustomerServiceClient>(s =>
{
    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding= new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(); 
    encoding.WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    var binding new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential); 
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
    var sbe = customBinding.Elements.Find<TransportSecurityBindingElement>();
    var httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
    httpsTransport.MaxBufferSize = 2000000000;
    httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize=2000000000;
    httpsTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize=2000000000;

    var dvsBinding = new CustomBinding(sbe, encoding, httpsTransport);
    dvsBinding.OpenTimeout new TimeSpan (0, 10, 0); 
    dvsBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan (0, 10, 0);
    dvsBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan (0, 10, 0);
    dvsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan (0, 10, 0);

    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceConfig.CustomerSvcUrl);

    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceConfig.TrustStore, serviceConfig.CertPassword);

    var client = new CustomerServiceClient(dvsBinding, endpointAddress); 
    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate; 
    return client;
});
```

It works on my machine, but throws Invalid URI exception on the pod.

Comment: Did the hosted programs and certificates change after the upgrade?

Comment: No, nothing changed in the code except upgrading the target framework and the nuget package versions. No changes to the certificates.

Comment: Did you use wcf trace to locate a specific problem?